# POM file for integrating Grails with Maven, with dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: maven, grails

I've got a Grails application as part of a larger Java source bas that's all built with Maven. I'd like to include the Grails app in the Maven continuous integration, nightly builds, etc.

(Ideally I'd also like it to be part of a Maven parent-project hierarchy, so I could pick up live code changes from other projects without having to install them into my local repository. I would also like a pony.)

I tried running "grails create-pom", setting "pom true" in BuildConfig.groovy, and using the POM to manage my dependencies. However, this left me stuck in [org.xml.sax.Locator classloader hell](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9283). So I went back to using BuildConfig.groovy for my dependencies.

I understand that "pom true" is a recent (Grails 2.1.0) feature, and it should be possible to integrate Grails into a Maven build while still managing dependencies in BuildConfig.groovy. Problem is, I can't find any documentation on what should go into the POM in that case. What do I put in my POM?

Comment: Using mvn dependency:tree you can see which dependencies pull in which xml libs. With this information you can exclude the specific xml libs for the specific dependencies.

Comment: Tried that, didn't work. (Also, as a side note, [dependency-tree is unreliable for Maven 3](https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution); you have to just run Maven with debug enabled.)

Comment: Frankly, I prefer BuildConfig.groovy. At least with it I don't need to separately exclude say stax or xml-apis for each dependency that pulls it in.

Comment: I also prefer BuildConfig in a pure Grails setting. But with Maven in the picture I would like to avoid keeping the dependencies up to date in two places. What you could do is have Maven use the Ant task to build the Grails application. This way Grails does the dependency management and you can use BuildConfig.groovy.

Comment: What do you mean by 'dependency-tree is unreliable for Maven 3'? The link gives 404. BTW. I don't see how your questions is related to groovy. There should be rather 'grails' tag instead of 'groovy' selected.

Comment: @topr It's available [from the Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20130530135909/https://cwiki.apache.org/MAVEN/maven-3x-compatibility-notes.html#Maven3.xCompatibilityNotes-DependencyResolution). Short version: Maven 3.x calculates dependencies differently from Maven 2.x, but `mvn dependency:tree` still uses the 2.x version, so its output "can differ from the actual dependency tree used by Maven itself to derive the classpaths of a project". This may have been fixed by now, I don't know.